# How fast decrease the Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given are the almost every where smooth, $2\pi $ periodic, absolutely integrable  function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$. In this case we have finite many points $\gamma_1,\dots ,\gamma_n\in [-\pi,\pi)$ where $f$ is not continuous, but every where else is $f$ smooth.  We can also assume that the limits $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x\pm h),\: \lim_{h\to0}f'(x\pm h)$ always exists for every $x\in \mathbb R$.
Now I want to show that $$c_k(f):=\frac 1 {2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$
does not decrease faster than $\tfrac 1{|k|}$.

So this is what I tried:
We can define the "sawtooth" function $$V_\gamma(x):=\cases {\tfrac 1 {2\pi}(\gamma -\pi-x)\quad,-\pi<x<\gamma\\\tfrac 1 {2\pi} (\gamma+\pi-x)\quad,\gamma\leq x\leq\pi}$$
which has a jump at $\gamma$ of magnitude $1$. The Fourier coefficients of $V_\gamma$ are given by
$$c_0(V_\gamma)=0,\qquad c_k(V_\gamma)=\tfrac 1 {2\pi i k}e^{-ik\gamma},\quad k=\pm1,\pm2,\dots$$
Let $A_j$ the magnitude of the jump of $f$ at $\gamma_j$, then we can define the $2\pi$ periodic, almost everywhere smooth, absolutely integrable function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$
$$g(x):=f(x)-\sum_{j=1}^n A_j V_{\gamma_j}(x).$$
We have now that $g$ is also continuously, so we know that $c_k(g)$ decrease faster to zero than $\tfrac 1{|k|}$. We get now by using the Fourier operator (and some small  equation manipulation)
$$c_k(f)=c_k(g)+\tfrac 1 {2\pi i k} \sum_{j=1} A_j e^{-ik\gamma_j}.$$
My Problem is now, that I don't have a good way to show that $\sum_{j=1}^nA_j e^{-ik\gamma_j}$ does not vanish for big $k$. It should be clear since $e^{-ik\gamma _j}$ is a kind of periodic and the $\gamma_j$ are all different to each other, but I don't want to go this way.

So does anyone have an idea how I could show that  $\sum_{j=1}^nA_j e^{-ik\gamma_j}$ does not vanish or maybe a total different way to show this?

Comment: It is a general result (not hard to prove using the fourier series of the fractional part) that if the Fourier series of an integrable function are $o(1/k)$ the function cannot have jump discontinuities; no other smoothnes hypothesis  needed

Comment: More generally at a jump discontinuity with jump $c \ne 0$ the conjugate Fourier series behaves asymptotically like $-c \log n/\pi$ which immediately gives the result above since the coefficients  of the conjugate series have same order magnitude so $c$ would need to be zero

Comment: @Conrad could you give me more detail of your first comment? Because if $c_k(f)=o(1/k)$ it does not follow that $\sum_k |c_k(f)|<\infty$. So we do not know directly that $\sum_{k=-n}^nc_k(f)e^{ikx}$ converges uniformly. So how do we know that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: The statement is that $f$ has no jump discontinuities (distinct left/right limits at a point) not that it is continuous (that would follow if $f$ has bounded variation for example or in your case by hypothesis) when it is (absolutely) integrable and has fourier coefficients $o(1/n)$; the reason is that at jump discontinuities the partial series of the conjugate fourier series are asymptotic with $\log n$ while the above estimate gives that those are $o(\log n)$; this is a general fourier series result which is not that hard to prove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$H(x)=\sum_k c_k(H) e^{i kx}$$ $2\pi$-periodic, $C^1$ and non-zero at $\gamma_j$ only for $j=1$.

Let $h_m(x)=e^{i m x}H(x)$ so that $$h_m(x)=\sum_k e^{ikx} c_{k-m}(H)$$

If $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^nA_j e^{ik\gamma_j}=0$ you'd get that
$$|A_1 H(\gamma_1)|=\lim_{m\to \infty}|\sum_{j=1}^n A_j h_m(\gamma_j)|=\lim_{m\to \infty} |\sum_k c_{k-m}(H) \sum_{j=1}^nA_j e^{ik\gamma_j}|=0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the last step, because I dont see why it has to go to $0$ by increasing $m$.
I understand it in the following way, is this correct ? 
\begin{align*}|A_1H(\gamma_1)|&=|A_1e^{-ik\gamma_1}H(\gamma_1)|\\
(1)&=|\sum_{j=0}^nA_je^{ik\gamma_j}H(\gamma_j)|\\
&=|\sum_{j=0}^ne^{-ik\gamma_j}\sum_r c_r(H)e^{ir\gamma_j}|\\
(2)&=|\sum_r c_r(H)\sum_{j=0}^nA_je^{-ik\gamma_j}e^{irk}|&\\
&=|\sum_rc_r(H)\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^nA_je^{i(r-k)\gamma_j}}_{\to 0 , k\to \infty}|\end{align*}
(1) $H(\gamma_j)=0$ for $j\not=1$ ,        
(2) changing sums since one is a finite sum

Comment: Yes, using that $c_r(H)$ is $\ell^1$ (following from $H\in C^1$) and $\sum_j A_j e^{i (r-k)\gamma_j}$ is bounded by some $B$ so $$|\sum_r c_r(H)\sum_j A_j e^{i (r-k)\gamma_j} - \sum_{|r|\le R} c_r(H)\sum_j A_j e^{i (r-k)\gamma_j}|\le B \sum_{|r|>R} |c_r(H)|$$ take $R$ large so that the RHS is small then take $k$ large so that the $\sum_{|r|\le R}$ is small. @Salfalur